# Password with special characters

Tags: login, special-characters

I accidentally created my password with numlock closed in terminal.

Now my password is pagedown, left cursor, right cursor, home, insert, insert  (346700)

I can't type this in gnome login because pagedown redirects to guest user login.

I can't login with virtual console(ctrl alt f1) because I believe they have different bash (sh and bash) so if I type those characters result returns different.

How can I login?

Comment: You should be able to login with Ctrl-Alt-F2. At the time you type the password, you're typing to `login`. The shell that's run is from `/etc/passwd`, do `getent passwd $USER | cut -d: -f7` to see it