# Login loop - Squares instead of letters in the username

Tags: boot, login, tty, 23.10

After upgrading to Ubuntu 23.10, I got a login loop problem. Also when I try to login through the tty, typing in a user gets these rectangles instead of the letters. When entering numbers, they are written normally.

[image: Squares instead of letters in username]

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the login loop issue which is quite separate. However, the comment by waltinator in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194539/password-with-special-characters) might help solve the issue.

Comment: The problem with the login loop is there. It turned out that I write in Cyrillic and I can't switch to Latin. That's why it writes squares in the user field. Is there a way to switch to Latin? The hotkey I set doesn't work after upgrading to Ubuntu 23.10.